# Passing parse.com information using Seague to change parseClassName

Tags: ios, objective-c, parsing

I set up my segue like this

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Check that a new transition has been requested to the DetailViewController and prepares for it
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"parse"]){

        // Capture the object (e.g. exam) the user has selected from the list
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        // Set destination view controller to DetailViewController to avoid the NavigationViewController in the middle (if you have it embedded into a navigation controller, if not ignore that part)
        FWProductTableViewController *detailViewController = (FWProductTableViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        detailViewController.exam = object;
        NSLog(@"%@", object);

    }
}
```

and in my detailTableViewController i have set it up like this.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.myClass = [self.exam objectForKey:@"serieClass"];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.myClass);

}

- (PFQuery *)queryForTable
{
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.myClass];


    return query;

}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aCoder];
    if (self) {
        // The className to query on
        NSLog(@"%@", self.exam);

        self.parseClassName = self.myClass;
        NSLog(@"%@ parseClassName",self.parseClassName);


        // The key of the PFObject to display in the label of the default cell style
        self.textKey = [self.exam objectForKey:@"navnFestival"];

        self.imageKey = @"produktBilde";

        self.textKey = @"serieFestival";

        // Whether the built-in pull-to-refresh is enabled
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;

        // Whether the built-in pagination is enabled
        self.paginationEnabled = NO;
    }
    return self;
}
```

In my mind it should be a valid way of doing it. But i get an console message saying

```
2015-03-22 17:09:09.814 Festival Fyrverkeri[1717:349918] 2015-12-31 17:00:00 +0000
2015-03-22 17:09:12.426 Festival Fyrverkeri[1717:349918] error: (null)
2015-03-22 17:09:12.647 Festival Fyrverkeri[1717:349918] error: (null)
2015-03-22 17:09:14.308 Festival Fyrverkeri[1717:349918] (null)
2015-03-22 17:09:14.309 Festival Fyrverkeri[1717:349918] (null) parseClassName
2015-03-22 17:09:14.310 Festival Fyrverkeri[1717:349918] <Serie: 0x14ed63b0, objectId: aXQehF5Rpr, localId: (null)> {
    serie = Blizzard;
    serieBeskrivelse = "Se hele Blizzard Serien";
    serieBilde = "<PFFile: 0x14f94520>";
    serieClass = Fyrverkeri;
}
2015-03-22 17:09:14.319 Festival Fyrverkeri[1717:349918] Fyrverkeri
2015-03-22 17:09:14.495 Festival Fyrverkeri[1717:349969] [Error]: bad characters in classname: (null) (Code: 103, Version: 1.6.4)
```

I can see the information is there, but it seems like parseClassName is loaded before the information is available for use. Anyone have an idea on how to fix this?

Comment: I have updated the question to be more spesific. Thank you for asking :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:[self.exam objectForKey:@"serieClass"]];
```